# How do I change the trigger for a modal form from a button to a link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please, I kindly need some assistance with a modal form implementation.

The code below was adapted from W3Schools, however, I have a problem changing the modal trigger from a button (as per below, in the full code body) to link.

I have tried replacing the button trigger with:

```
<a href="id01">Change Password</a>
```

But it won’t work. Upon clicking the link, it requests a non-existent URL. Can some please advise me on how to solve this?

The full code is below:

```
<div id='changePasswordModalButton'>
                    <!-- Button to open the modal Change Password form -->
                    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'block'">Change Password</button>
                </div>

                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div id="id01" class="modal">
                    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                    <!-- Modal Content -->
                    <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php">
                        <div class="container">
                            <label><b>Current Password*</b></label>
                            <input type="password" name="currentPassword" placeholder="Enter your current password" value="" required/>
                            <label><b>New Password*</b></label>
                            <input type="password" name="currentPassword" placeholder="Enter new password" value="" required/>
                            <label><b>Confirm New Password*</b></label>
                            <input type="password" name="currentPassword" placeholder="Confirm new password" value="" required/>
                            <button type="submit">Update Password</button>
                            <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
                                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="mandatoryFields">
                                <h4>* Mandatory Fields</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <script>
                    // Get the modal
                    var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
                    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                    window.onclick = function (event) {
                        if (event.target === modal) {
                            modal.style.display = "none";
                        }
                    };
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to change this button:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'block'">Change Password</button>
```

with a link.

To do it, the steps are:

1. replace `button` with `a` (but keep all the attributes)
2. add an `href` attribute. Since you won't use it, let's make it point to the current page using `#`.
3. prevent the link's default behavior (i.e. to try to open a page on click) by adding a `return false` at the end of the `onclick` attribute.

The result is:

```
 <a href="#"
    onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'block'; return false">Change Password
 </a>
```

---

Note that using an `onclick` attribute is not the best way to go. A better way would be to use an event listener, as you did for the close event:

```
document.getElementById("myLink").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // instead of "return false"
    document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'block';
});
```

Using this solution, don't forget to remove the `onclick` attribute and to add an `id` to your link:

```
 <a href="#" id="myLink">Change Password</a>
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, Derlin.

Comment: It is not recommended to handle the onclick inside the onclick. It is better practice to use an event handler like he was originally doing and use the `Event.preventDefault()` function. The old method was to `return false` which is not recommended anymore. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation

Comment: I agree, but for a beginner I think it is best to use the old trick (and understand it) before moving to jQuery and other tools.

Comment: No, a beginner should not be using `return false` inside inline onclick property. No one should. You do not need a tool to use `Event.preventDefault()` it is standard JavaScript.

Comment: I gave the solution with the less change (and the closer to his attempt). But I got your point and updated the answer to include your comment.

Comment: The least amount of change is simply adding one line to his existing solution: add `event.preventDefault()` above `modal.style.display = "none";` which I provided in my answer. Also, please do not consider w3schools to be a reliable resource. See: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1):

The default action for a click on a link is to follow the link. You will need to prevent that default using `Event.preventDefault()`

```
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    event.preventDefault();
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

You should also consider attaching the event handler to the target instead of the window.

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
modal.onclick = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    modal.style.display = "none";
};
```

And the modern syntax would be:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
modal.addEventListener( 'click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    modal.style.display = "none";
}, false);
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener